# Filtering OpenStreetMap 3d buildings in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, openstreetmap, global-scene, living-atlas

I am trying to display the 3d buildings in a city and I am using the Open street map 3D Buildings from ArcGIS Living Atlas. When I load it into my 3D scene, I see all the buildings outside my desired area. [image]